# Obj-c - one if Statement overriding the other?

Tags: objective-c

I have two if statements - see code below:

**.m**

```
if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [friends count] > 0) {

} 

if ([friends count] > 0) {

}
```

As is, my second if statement sometimes overrides the first, even if value for swaptime is populated **AND** friends count is greater than 0. Even though both statements require friends count to be greater than 0, Shouldn't the second if statement kick in ONLY if swaptime is NULL? Or is there another way that I should be writing this?

Comment: Both of them can execute as written.  Maybe you want the second one as an "else if"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [friends count] > 0) 
{

} 
else if ([friends count] > 0) 
{

}
```

The way you have it the second if is executed whenever [friends count] > 0, disregarding whether [swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] is true.

Duplication of code is generally a bad thing. I'd say that:

```
if ([friends count] > 0)
{
    if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

would make for more intelligible code...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `else if ([friends count] > 0)`.. OR write them as consecutive condition statements OR nested statements.

Example 1:

```
if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [friends count] > 0) {
    //Execute code where because swapTime is `NSString` and `friends.count > 0`..
} 
else if ([friends count] > 0) {
    //Execute code here if `swapTime` is anything other than `NSString` (including nil) and `friends count > 0`
}
```

Example 2:

```
if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [friends count] > 0) {
    //Execute code where because swapTime is `NSString` and `friends.count > 0`..
} 
else if (swaptime != nil && [friends count] > 0) {
    //Execute code here if `swapTime` is non-null and not `NSString` and `friends count > 0`
}
else if ([friends count] > 0) {
    //Execute code here if `swapTime` is null/nil and `friends count > 0`
}
```

Example 3:

```
if ([friends count] > 0) {
    if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        //Execute code here if swapTime is NSString..
    }
    else if (swaptime) {
        //Execute code here if swapTime is non-null and NOT an NSString..
    }
    else {
        //Execute code here if swapTime is null..
    }
}
```